# Cordova Opening External URL with no Cache

Tags: android, cordova, caching

I have a already working web application that I am trying to open using cordova container, it works fine so far but the problem I am facing is that I have to clear the cache of mobile application whenever there is any update on the server.

Is there anyways I can disable the caching permanently to view the latest state of application.

Comment: are you using inappbrowser to load webview in the app?

Comment: No, not in app browser. The web page opens up inside the application just like a normal application. I am using whitelist plugin for this with this setting
<allow-navigation href="myurl" />